# Tracking development and staging environment

Tags: windows, configuration-management

I'm working in a small development shop that maintains a fairly large number of custom software products.  They have 3 environments -- Test, Staging, and Production where software is run from.  The vast majority are web applications (ASP.NET) while a few are scheduled applications or Windows Services.  The applications all interact with one another via ASP.NET Web Services, a handful of WCF services, and DLL libraries, and all share a significant number of databases.

The management team is looking for a solution to keep track of all of the instances of software running on the different servers -- Application A depends on B and C, and uses Database X with login credentials LMNOP etc.

Are there any off-the-shelf products out there that can help with this task, or are we better off developing something from scratch?

Comment: are you looking for a  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management_database?

Comment: Yes, that may be what we're looking for.  Ideally they would like it to be auto-updating -- have an agent that pings each IIS server for new and removed Virtual Directories every so often, and reads the web.config file for each application to discover database connections and web service URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use CruiseControl but I plan to use TeamCity with RedGate for DB source control. I also have 3 environments (team city is free up to 3).